# How to mock a constant that is instantiated outside a function?

Tags: javascript, mocking, mocha.js, chai

I have a constant that is instantiated outside a function, and I wish to unit test that function. But I don't want to update my unit test result every time I update that constant. Is there any way to mock that constant and "tell the function" to use the mocked one instead of the actual constant? I would rather prefer not having to create a new function that returns that constant (which I found was possible).

utils.js

```
const data = [1, 2, 3]

const functionToTest = () => {
    if (data.includes(2)) {
        return true
    }

    return false
}
```

test.js

```
describe('testing functionToTest', () => {
    const dataReplacement = [3, 4, 5]

    tellFunctionToTest('hey, use dataReplacement instead of data')
})
```

I know I could pass data as a parameter, but I would rather not if it's possible. Thanks for the help !

Comment: you cant change the value of a `const`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to export `data` and use the export in `functionToTest`:

code.js

```
exports.data = [1, 2, 3];

exports.functionToTest = () => exports.data.includes(2);
```

code.test.js

```
const assert = require('assert');
const code = require('./code');

describe('functionToTest', () => {
  it('should work', () => {
    code.data = [3, 4, 5];
    assert(code.functionToTest() === false);  // Success!
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can mock it by assigning the value to the `global` variable:

```
test('testing functionToTest', () => {
    global.data = [3, 4, 5];
   // continue the test
})
```

**Edit**

Just created a simple example to show how you can declare the globals:
https://codesandbox.io/s/9q1x757my?fontsize=14

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this doesn't seem to be working :/

Comment: @ArnaudRochez, please check the given example and try to apply to your code. Thank you.